# Javascript RegEx How To

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I want to extract `"abc"` from `"images/abc.png"` using **Javascript Regular experssion in one line.**

i have tried this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var str = "images/abc.png";
var patt1 = /images\/[a-z]+?/i;
document.write(str.split(patt1));
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a *capture group*, e.g.:

```
var match = "images/abc.png".match(/images\/([^.]+)\.png/);
var text = match && match[1];
```

You can do it on one line only if you *know* that it will match; otherwise you'll get an exception.

Actually, I could cheat and use the comma operator to get it on one line:

```
var match = "images/abc.png".match(/images\/([^.]+)\.png/), text = match && match[1];
```

...but I think it looses a lot of clarity.

The [MDC page on regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) is useful reading.

Comment: great work, i want to be master in regex, can you suggest me any URL for tutorial

Answer (score 1):

With capturing:

```
var text = "images/abc.png".replace(/^.*?\/(.*?)\.[^.]*$/, '$1');
```

or without capturing:

```
var text = "images/abc.png".replace(/^.*?\//, '').replace(/\.[^.]*$/, '');
```

if you want to match for `images/`, then you should replace the first `.*?` to `images`.